# Hide tabs if content is empty

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, prestashop

I am creating a shop using prestashop.
My problem is, in product description I have two bootstrap tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#op">One</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#conf">Spec</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first one is general description and the other one is more technical.
But not every product has that second description, so the content is empty.

My question is, how can i make only first tab visible when there is need to?

EDIT:
Guys I don't know if I wrote that straight.
I need tab to be hidden when the div content it 'points' on is empty.

Thanks

Comment: What defines when the first tab needs to be visible or hidden?

Comment: Could you also provide the markup when spec is not available? Basically you just need to hide the <li> it is the only one?

Comment: Yes, i only need to hide the <li> thing.

I want <li> to be hidden when the div is like this:
<div id="conf" class="tab-pane fade"> </div>

Comment: Sounds to be like this should be done using PHP at the back-end (or whatever language you're using) - not done at the front-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `class` inside your second tab,and run this Jquery

```
  $(".someclass").each(function(){
    var $txt=$(this).text();
    if($txt==""){
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
    }
    })
```

<kbd>[**Without text DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/xbf4r3aw/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**With text DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/0ufo7qcb/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**For Multiple empty tab contents**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/2vpybjs6/3/)</kbd>

Comment: It does not work :(. I tried to put like "tab" text into the tab content and changed the  if($txt=="tab") but it still didn't work

Comment: You mean if the tab-content is empty you want to hide that tab. right ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this: <div id="conf" class="tab-pane fade"></div>

Comment: Do you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/xFW8t/882/),[without text](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/xFW8t/882/)

Comment: Exacly! But is it possible to apply it to every tab? Not only to #profle?

Comment: I think you need to write for other tabs using ids

Comment: Generalized [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/2vpybjs6/3/) if there are many tabs with no content.

Answer (score 0):

This should to it:

```
$('.nav-tabs li').each(function () {
    $tab = $(this)
    if ($tab.text() === '') {
        $tab.hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that too but with no results

Comment: Can you try to put a `console.log($tab.text())` before the if-condition to check what the text actually is? Maybe there are some additional spaces in there.

Comment: The console outputs my tabs names, not it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late! But i write my answer here to help somebody.
I had a nav-tab like this with bootstrap that i wanted to hide the tabs with no content:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="descriptionTab">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#introduction" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">introduction</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#access" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">access</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#times" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">times</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content" style="position:relative;">                  
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in EmptyFind" id="introduction">
        <h2>some text here</h2>               
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade EmptyFind" id="access">
        <h2>some text here</h2>               
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade EmptyFind" id="times">
        <h2>    <!--   no content or some whitespace   -->    </h2>               
    </div>
</div>
```

So we can add these lines of jquery code to hide "#times" tab that has no content in it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.EmptyFind').each(function() {
            var $txt=$(this).text().trim().length;
            var $dataTarget=$(this).attr('id');            
            if ($txt < 1) {
                $('#descriptionTab a[href="#' + $dataTarget + '"]').closest('li').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope it will be helpfull :)